# What is this design pattern called?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Take a bunch of `IProcess` implementations find the correct one based on what the implementation `CanProcess`.

```cs
public interface IProcess
{
    bool CanProcess(string name);
    Task Process();
}

public class Processor
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IProcess> _processors;

    public Processor(IEnumerable<IProcess> processors)
    {
        _processors = processors;
    }

    public void Process(string name)
    {
        Guard.RequireNonNullOrEmpty(name, "name");

        // this could allow for processing multiple matches
        var processor = _processors.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CanProcess(name));
        if (processor!= null)
        {
            processor.Process();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise on the name of this pattern, looked at a few but it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: It's a `Command` pattern that's also using the `Tester/Doer` pattern.

Comment: What is the name of pattern here for locating the correct `IProcess` implementation as their could be many that are not suitable.

Comment: I don't think there's a pattern to describe that. It's just a query. Not every bit of code needs to be related to a formal design pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it essentially a [Command Processor](http://wiki.hsr.ch/APF/files/CommandProcessor.pdf)?

Comment: What I am looking really is the name of the pattern of using `CanProcess` to locate `IProcess` implementations which can satisfy `name`.

Comment: As I've said above, that's not really a formal design pattern. It's just a query. You might be able to argue that it's a form of Service Location?

Comment: Ok thanks, I prefer the idea that its just a query rather than Service Location as this is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes. It's not really Service Location as you're injecting the suitable processors in the constructor. Furthermore, it could probably be more efficient as the `FirstOrDefault()` is just a foreach. Using a Dictionary would be better for a large number of processors.

Comment: Well the idea behind this is that the `IProcess` knows what it can Process, how would I swap the `FirstOrDefault()` iteration for a version that uses the dictionary when `CanHandle` needs be called to discover a suitable `IProcess`?

Comment: Yes. It's a technique I use with factories quite a lot. I don't think it's watertight from a polymorphic perspective, but it works well and, IMHO, is an elegant solution. My point about the Dictionary is that processors could be keyed by the name of the process they support, allowing more efficient finding. It's just something I was thinking about for my own implementations of this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like poor man's [chain of responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern). If instead a `Processor` you modify `IProcess` (and its implementations) to allow build up a correlated chain you get the same behaviour plus the the ability to process the same data in various process just in case you need it.

Comment: I agree it does look similar and at first I thought it might be chain of responsibility, it certainly solves a similar problem and in a similar way.